# How to hide the first tr using classname in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide the rest all tr except parent tr.
the code to show the dynamic controls are as mentioned,
and the code is inside the for each loop

```
<tr id='package_<%=option.Option-id %>' class='package-flights'>
  <table>
    <TD>
     <input type="text" id="text1">
    <TD>
   <table>
</tr>
```

hence if have the more option it will display the all the text box.
Can any one find the solution for the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attribute selector starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get all rows having id starting with `package_`, then use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the first using [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$('[id^=package_]').not(':first').hide();
```

Comment: i tried with this ,$('td.packageFlights').not(':first').find('.first_td').hide(); but it dint worked out

Answer (score 0):

Try the class selector then use .slice() to get all elements after the first one and then hide

```
$('.package-flights').slice(1).hide();
```